# Display correct choice text for Django inline formset with two foreign keys

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have successfully used inline formsets to create a recipe input form that consists of a Recipe form (just a model form) and a RecipeIngredient formset.  The models are:

```
#models.py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    directions = models.TextField()

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    unit_of_measure = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=UNIT_CHOICES)
    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=INGREDIENT_CHOICES)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
```

I want to change the ingredient to the following:

```
ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
```

Where Ingredient is:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I left views.py unchanged to set up the inline formset:

```
FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, RecipeIngredient, extra=1,
            can_delete=False)
```

And everything worked perfectly ... until I clicked the ingredient drop down and saw nothing but "Ingredient object" choices repeated for every ingredient entry rather than the title value I was looking for.

Is there any way to maintain this straight forward approach and display Ingredient.title in the dropdowns?  Will this have any other problems wrt saving, displaying, etc.?

Failing that, what do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks all.

Comment: Apologies for the cruddy formatting; first post.

Comment: Stack Overflow has online help regarding formatting operations. Please avail yourself of it.

Comment: Took a few moments to find it but ... advice followed.

Comment: Hmmm ... looks like this doesn't save correctly to the db either if you blindly choose one of the drop down choices.  And HTML manipulations don't seem to change the display, at least none of the manipulations I could think of.  Hope of a trivial answer fades ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is indeed trivial: just define a `__unicode__` method on the Ingredient model to return `self.title`.

Comment: *sigh*  Trivial indeed. Thanks very much, I could have stared at that for days.